# Error on d3 arc generator used in Angular app for pie chart

Tags: angular, d3.js, donut-chart

I have an Angular app and I'm trying to create a pie chart in one component using v7 of D3. For now I kept the code inside onInit:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    let data = [2,4,7,11,43,20]
    let svg = d3.select("svg");
    let width = Number(svg.attr('width'));
    let height = Number(svg.attr('height'));
    let radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;    
    
    let g = svg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate('+ width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')');

    let color = d3.scaleOrdinal(['#e40303','#ff8c00', '#ffed00', '#008026','#004dff','#750787']);
    let pie = d3.pie();    
    
    let arcGenerator = d3.arc()
                .innerRadius(0)
                .outerRadius(radius);
                console.log(arcGenerator);
    let arcs = g.selectAll('.arc')
                .data(pie(data))
                .enter().append('g')
                .attr('class','arc');
                  
    arcs.append('path')
        .attr('fill', (d, i: any) => {
          return color(i)
        })
          .attr('d', arcGenerator);      
    }
```

This is the HTML:

```
<svg width="600" height="200"></svg>
```

I'm getting an error from the last line because of the argGenerator, but I used it in the same way as all the examples I've seen. If I remove that line, the svg shows up, but the arcs have 0x0 dimensions. Is it because of Angular, or was the function changed with this version?

Comment: I got this to run in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o4hg3n0y/#&togetherjs=xvDNlkhexq. Note that I removed the `any` type annotation.